# Interpolating in a table

Tags: java, interpolation

The Following is a table i have from which i want to interpolate between the values

```
+---+----+----+----+----+ . . . .
|   | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | . . . .
+---+----+----+----+----+ . . . .
|100| 78 | 89 | 92 | 95 | . . . .
+---+----+----+----+----+ . . . .
|200| 62 | 76 | 88 | 91 | . . . .
+---+----+----+----+----+ . . . .
|300| 59 | 68 | 74 | 83 | . . . .
+---+----+----+----+----+ . . . .
|400| 48 | 50 | 65 | 72 | . . . .
+---+----+----+----+----+ . . . .
```

The user inputs a speed and a temperature value.

I know how to do this mathematically but bringing it over to java has just stumped me.

So if the user inputs a speed of 200 (there is no 250, either 200 or 300) and a temperature of 34 (only whole number inputs) 
Mathematically I would do;

```
+---+----+----+----+----+ . . . .
|   |    | 30 | 34  | 40 | . . . . 
+---+----+----+----+----+ . . . .
|200|    | 76 |  x  | 88 | . . . . 
+---+----+----+----+----+ . . . .


(76 - 88) /10 = 1.2
1.2 * (34-30) = 4.8
4.8 + 76 = 80.8 = x
```

we should get an answer of 80.8

**EDIT** I'm not a lazy ass who expect you guys to do all the work for me like how SOME people think. I am not just posting my problem here and expecting a fully working code! ANY **IDEAS** on how to proceed with this problem is all i am asking, Just as how i have mentioned above. Thankyou!

Comment: This is not a platform where people will code answers for you !. Please post the work what you have done & ask people about specific problems. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Forgive me for my Dumbness and posting here without reading the rules and Thank you for your contribution kind sir.

Comment: Post the code you have tried, even that is not working, so that we known what level of assist you need. If you don't know how to start, build a 2D-array to represent your table first, then read user input by `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 2D-Array to store your table. Use `Scanner` to read user input. Calculate the row index and column index from the input. Get the corresponding numbers from the 2D-Array then do the calculation.

```
    int[][] table = {
        {78,89,92,95},
        {62,76,88,91},
        {59,68,74,83},
        {48,50,65,72}
    };

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter speed:");
    int speed = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter temperature:");
    int temp = scanner.nextInt();
    int row = (speed / 100) - 1;
    int col = (temp / 10)  - 2;
    float a = table[row][col];
    float b = table[row][col + 1];
    float result = a + (temp % 10) * (b - a) / 10;
    System.out.println(result);
```